# Can I use 100μF and 47μF as input and output capacitor, respectively, for regulator LM7924CT?

Tags: capacitor, voltage-regulator

I have one LM7924CT regulator, but only have 100μF and 47μF capacitors at hand, can I use them? Would 47μF be too large for the output capacitor?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the values given in data sheet if possible. Order some more caps you will surly need them sooner or later. The data sheet also states:

"If large capacitors are used, a high current diode from input to output (1N400l or similar)
should be introduced to protect the device from momentary input short circuit"

Not sure if this is valid when you are using it as a single supply.

Comment: It is valid I reckon, the diode that it. Also the real problem with normal 47uF caps is that they are probably electrolytic and won't have a very good impedance up in the 100s of kilohertz. Use what is recommended as per what user1840438 says +1

Comment: The datasheet also mentions that if one are to use electrolytic capacitors: "For value given, capacitor must be solid tantalum. If aluminium electronics are used, at least ten times
value shown should be selected", but use what is recommened, it is recommended for a reason.